# I thought the enter-key would make a new line while typing a comment, but instead, it submitted it b4 I was done writing. So

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

Meta: I thought the enter-key would make a new line while typing a comment, but instead, it submitted it before I was finished writing it. So, should this be changed?

I can see how edits-only-within-5-minutes is a good idea. But I wasn't expecting the enter-key to submit my comment right away. And I'm the type of person who can only write a really long "first-draft" to my comments/posts, after which I have to cut it down to a reasonable length before submitting. So I like to put enter-lines in between. 5 minutes wasn't enough for me. And I'm guessing that shift+enter is an option, but I didn't know at the time.

It's not a big deal, but just suggesting a meta-topic. Thoughts?

Comment: There's no mechanism accessible to the community to configure this, so this is a feature request for the SE team.

Shift-enter is an option, but it doesn't "do anything." It inserts line breaks in the input field, but the line breaks are not preserved when the comment is rendered.

(There are shift-enter line breaks between each of my sentences in this comment.)

Comment: I think this is a case of requesting functionality that is not suitable for the intended purpose of comments.  You shouldn't be making long first drafts of comments; they're not intended as permanent content.

Comment: I know comments should be short. That's why I edit them after. i.e. what I meant was: i'm bad at writing concise comments. So I wanna edit them into concise ones before submitting, with a few lines in between. Sorry if i was unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a site wide feature & has already been raised on [SE meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197/how-about-newlines-within-comments).

The presently stated rationale is that line breaks would lead to longer, more conversational style commenting. Comments are intended for brief meta Q&A rather than discussions.

From time to time, I've found myself trying to line break my own comments - I've always found that my content could either be made more concise or wasn't suited to comments to begin with.